# How to combine multiple features into KMeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, scikit-image

I try to cluster images, based on their edges-features.

Following method extract edges of each image:

```
from skimage.filters import prewitt_h,prewitt_v
from skimage.filters import roberts_pos_diag, roberts_neg_diag
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

features=[]    
def extract_edges(img):
     edges_h = prewitt_h(img)
     edges_v = prewitt_v(img)
     edges_d = roberts_pos_diag(img)
     edges_nd = roberts_neg_diag(img)
     return (edges_h, edges_v, edges_d, edges_nd)

features.append(extract_edges(img))
```

After loading some images, I try to fit e KMeans to these features, what throws the following exception:

```
kmeans_pca = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=42).fit(features)
>> ValueError: Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2.
```

Do I still have to vectorize the features? How would I do it best?

Comment: firstly, you probably want to use a histogram of edges, e.g. HOG (histogram of oriented gradients). Here, if your image is shifted by one pixel, your features will no longer line up. But secondly, yes, a feature vector for kmeans needs to be a vector, so you probably want to use `np.concatenate(list(map(np.ravel, extract_edges(img))))` to get a feature vector. But again, these are not the right features.

Comment: Thx @Juan for your comment and the hints. You're absolutly right - these features are not right and i should use a histogram instead of the raw-values. Does it make sense to reduce the features (histogram of edges) with a PCA and cluster the results in KMeans or can this have negative effects?

Comment: I think so, but you'll have to try it on your data. The equivalent text classification method is "bag-of-words", this would be "bag-of-edges". =) More generic is "bag-of-patches", which you can Google for inspiration.